# Conditional formatting in Dash Table is not working

Tags: plotly-dash

I am trying to color some cells based on their numerical value but the code doesn't work (Doesn't display anything). Is there a way to fix it?

I have tried using all techniques mentioned in Dash Table Documentation (https://dash.plot.ly/datatable/style) it didnt work. Also upgraded the libraries to latest version and the code stopped displaying even the table, so I switched back to older version of Dash_Table

```
{'if': {'column_id': '24H Base', 'filter': 'num(24H Base) > num(4)'},
'backgroundColor': '#3D9970',
'color': 'white'}
```

1. On using latest libraries - Even table isnt displayed
2. Older Libraries (Dash Table v 3.7) Code doesnt format specific cell, but the table is displayed

Both cases No error message is displayed

Answer (score 0):

Try `filter_query` instead of `filter`:

```
{'if': {'column_id': '24H Base', 'filter_query': 'num(24H Base) > num(4)'},
'backgroundColor': '#3D9970',
'color': 'white'}
```