# Conditionally formatting values in Dash data table (Julia)

Tags: datatable, formatting, julia, plotly-dash

I've built a table in Dash using Julia:

```
df = DataFrame(Day=["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday"],
               Object=["Egg","Cat","Phone"],
               Letters=["A","B","C"],
               Food=["Milk","Egg","Cheese"])

app = dash()

app.layout = html_div() do
    dash_datatable(id="data_table",
                   columns = tuple([(name=x,id=x) for x in names(df)])[1],
                   data = df_to_datatable(df),
                   style_cell = (textAlign="center", fontSize=16,
                                 backgroundColor="rgb(50,50,50)",
                                 color="white"),
                   style_header = (backgroundColor="rgb(30, 30, 30)",),
                   style_table = (textAlign="center", minwidth="35%",
                                  width="35%",maxwidth="35%",
                                  marginLeft="auto",marginRight="auto"),
                   #style_cell_conditional = (if(filter_query="Egg"), backgroundColor="#3D9970"),
                  ),
    html_div(id="output_div")
end
```

Resulting in this table:

[image]

I'm trying to conditionally format cells that contain "Egg", but I'm having trouble.  I've tried following [other](https://community.plotly.com/t/dash-v1-12-0-release-pattern-matching-callbacks-fixes-shape-drawing-new-datatable-conditional-formatting-options-prevent-initial-call-and-more/38867) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57134968/conditional-formatting-in-dash-table-is-not-working) and the [documentation](https://juliahub.com/docs/DashTable/OyY8N/4.10.1/autodocs/) for DashTable, converting the Python syntax to Julia.  I've also tried addressing errors produced by my attempts (ex. "LoadError: syntax: unexpected ',' ") with no success. Would appreciate any help!

Edit: I've also been consulting the [conditional formatting documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/conditional-formatting), but the syntax is Python, which I'm still having trouble converting to Julia.

Comment: Thank you for the link, @as11 -- I've been using this page as a reference, but I'm still having trouble converting the Python syntax to Julia. It's helpful, but does not immediately answer my question.

Comment: @BasvanderLinden -- as it is, the code generates the table shown. no syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't use `filter_query` with `style_cell_conditional`.

We can use `filter_query` with `style_data_conditional` like this:

```
style_data_conditional = [
    Dict(
        "if" =>
            Dict("column_id" => "$(column)", "filter_query" => "{$(column)} = 'Egg'"),
        "backgroundColor" => "blue",
    ) for column in names(df)
]
```

Result:

[image]

---

The above does an exact match for `'Egg'`. If you want to match all words that contain `"Egg"` you can use `contains` instead of `=`.